How to correctly import FBX, OBJ, Max files with right materials?
I tried to import this couch model from 3D Sky. I got a lot of formats for the same model, Vray FBX, Corona FBX, OBJ, Max etc. I wanted the model to display in it's correct materials in blender. I also went ahead to reassign those materials in the texture folder provided with the model. But somehow I am lacking a certain material or the materials are just not showing the way it should in the original model. Here are images for reference.
Left one is FBX and Right one is OBJ.



Also, why are the models low poly:

The Original Folder:
https://easyupload.io/jd1z03

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Please do not ask two different in the same post. But just a quick remark to second question: What do you mean by low poly? First of all, why that screenshot to this question, there is no mesh visible? Then, the OBJ and FBX files have over 339,000 triangles which is not exactly low poly, the MAX files have over 180,000 triangles. Only the 3DS file has "just" over 60,000 triangles, but still not exactly low poly. How many polygons did you expect the model to have, was there a number given somewhere which was higher?
